# Python: handling exceptions with re.compile

Tags: python, regex, string

Say you want to find out whether a specific word is contained in a string:

```
import re

def findword(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search
```

this will work and will return the match if it is found. However, say you want to return 1 if the match is found, and 0 otherwise, such as:

```
import re

def findword(w):
    if re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search is not None:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

However, when I run the latter, I get:
`TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` with any word I use as argument. How should I handle the case when the match is returned and when it isn't?

Comment: what's the input string?

Comment: Any input string, really.

Comment: Use `.search(s)` where `s` is the input string. You may change the method definition to `def findword(w,s):`

Comment: No repro. I get 1 as the result from `findword`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Show us the line that gives the error message `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. It can't occur in the code you present. The issue is almost certainly that the first version of the function returns a callable and the second version returns an integer.